# GET request with axios resulting in 404

Tags: axios, http-status-code-404

I've been hardstuck on an issue where an API request results in a 404 no matter what I try. The strange part is that everything seems to be working as expected when doing the exact same API request through postman.

So the project I am working on is a customized user registration and login, using Django as backend. The authentication is the default credential login which issues access and refresh tokens using SimpleJWT, whenever only these tokens are being used for accessing other restricted views everything seems to be working fine, which leads me to believe that the issue is in the frontend of the application.

For the frontend framework I am using React with Redux, Thunk and Axios.

The issue happens right after login, when load_user is being dispatched.

```
export const login = (email, password) =\> async dispatch =\> {
const config = {
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
};

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/account/user-login/`, body, config);
    
        console.log('Login Successful.');
        
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: {
                user: res.data.user,
                access: res.data.access_token,
                refresh: res.data.refresh_token
            },
        });
    
        // Load user data
        dispatch(load_user());
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Login Failed.', err);
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL
        });
    }

};
```

Here's the load_user action:

```
export const load_user = () => async (dispatch) => {     console.log(localStorage.getItem('access'))     if (localStorage.getItem('access')) {         const config = {             headers: {                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',                 'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access')}\`,
'Accept': 'application/json'
}
};
console.log(config)

        try {
            console.log(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/account/get_user_data/`)
            const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/account/get_user_data/`, config);
    
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED_FAIL,
            });
        }
    } else {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED_FAIL,
        });
    }

};
```

When checking the browser console log, everything required for the login is present before the axios.get request is being made, all the headers and the correct url, however the django terminal response with this:

"OPTIONS /account/user-login/ HTTP/1.1" 200
"POST /account/user-login/ HTTP/1.1" 200
"OPTIONS /account/get_user_data/ HTTP/1.1" 200
"GET /account/get_user_data/ HTTP/1.1" 302
"OPTIONS /accounts/login/?next=/account/get_user_data/ HTTP/1.1" 200
Not Found: /accounts/login/
Not Found: /accounts/login/
"GET /accounts/login/?next=/account/get_user_data/ HTTP/1.1" 404

When checking the states in Redux DevTools, LOGIN_SUCCESS auth contains access and refresh tokens, as isAuthenticated: true as well as other user data. But then USER_LOADED_FAIL happens, this still contain the access and refresh tokens, but isAuthenticated: false and user: null.

I've exhausted all other ideas to fix this, and would very much appreciate any tips!

Django-Cors-Headers,
Verified that tokens are in fact being used for authentication by the backend,
Tested both restricted and unrestricted views with the same access tokens that generates the error, using postman,
Tried multiple different ways of sending the token with the get request.
Changed the order of middleware for the backend,
Created brand new views to try the get request on, but resulting in the same issue,

Here's the view I am trying to reach:

```
@login_required()
@require_GET
def get_user_data(request):
    print('Hello World')
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
        user_data = {
            'id': user.id,
            'email': user.email,
            # Add other user profile fields as needed
        }
        return JsonResponse(user_data)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'User is not authenticated'}, status=401)
```

And not even Hello World is being printed.

I've tested the same view with and without the login_required decorator.
With results in the redirect and 404, without results in a direct 401 unauthorized.